# How to access a SMB server with PHP on Both Windows and Linux servers?

Tags: php, linux, windows, samba

I have a PHP script that generates an html file with data from a `POST` request (the file is a Thunderbird signature). I need to put this file in a folder on a SMB server.

I have already made a working script in Java to create the folders and blank html files (so that Thunderbird doesn't freak out) on my SMB server, using the [JCIFS Library](http://jcifs.samba.org/). I log in to SMB with a static domain and a given username & password.

Also, the password contains special characters such as `@` and that could conflict with the basic `smb://WORKGROUP;user:password@host` [syntax](http://wp.natsci.colostate.edu/cnsit/samba-smb-syntax/) I guess.

Now, this works on Java just fine since I needed a cron, but now I have to do it on PHP since it has to be done right when the user validates the HTML form.

The thing is that I don't know if the script will be put on a Windows Server or a Linux Server since we use both. I'm using Wamp (= Xampp) right now tho.

I have found a few methods to do what I need, including [this library](https://github.com/icewind1991/SMB) by Icewind as well as [libsmbclient](https://github.com/eduardok/libsmbclient-php). The thing is libsmbclient requires to be built on GNU/Linux. And the former library doesn't seem to support domain names as the Server class's constructor only takes these three arguments :

```
public function __construct($host, $user, $password) {
    $this->host = $host;
    $this->user = $user;
    $this->password = $password;
}
```

So I don't really know what way (or library) to use to do the task I need as smb isn't supported by default in PHP. Also, the fact that I don't know if the script will be ran on Win or Nux is not helping.

Perhaps there is a way to do this that I don't know of, and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Coloco

Comment: I guess the user you wan't to login to the SMB server isn't static? If it was, the easiest way by far would be to mount the SMB share as a folder natively within the OS, and just use normal filesystem functions.

Comment: I mean the user is static for now, but it could very well change in the future I guess. Tho I made it work flawlessly in Java (with JCIFS) so I don't see why couldn't I do the same thing in PHP... I guess I could still do a cron every minute or so in Java instead but I'm not sure all of my coworkers would like that (even if it only does a simple MySQL query with only a few rows returned)

Comment: Also doesn't PHP's `fopen` work with symbolic links (`//`) ? But only on the local server, right ?

Comment: If you don't have to change users I would think that the simplest solution is to mount the damn thing and just use it as if it was a normal part of your FS. Its sad that there isn't a PHP extension that works for you in both environments, but the more you use PHP the more you come to realize that it isn't really as crossplatform as it seems to be.

Comment: I guess I'll ask my tutor about that (I'm in internship atm) and I'll see which way (PHP and mounts, or Java) we decide to go. Thanks for the helpful comments

Comment: I just did a little google search for you :-). It seems like someone has made bindings for the smbclient CLI for nix systems, and there also exists an exact port of that client for windows, so combining the two could be a cross platform solution:
SMBclient for windows: https://www.leepa.io/lpackham/smbclient/ ... Some dudes PHP binding class for that CLI: http://smorgasbork.com/component/content/article/66-accessing-smb-servers-with-php

Comment: Yeah I had found the second link already which was for Linux and I spent a few hours searching for a way to make something like that on Win, and I never found the Windows port. Thank you very much, I'll look into that and get back to you if I can't make it work :)

Comment: Alright, asked my tutor and we're going with a Java cron. Will be much less of a hassle than to install all those libraries on the server.

Comment: I agree! Use the best tool for the job! Unfortunately PHP tends to be a hammer made of wet cardboard when it comes to some tasks :-)